# Can you have a matrix with no zero rows that has an eigenvalue equal to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can you have a matrix with no zero rows that has an eigenvalue equal to zero?

So for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with $0$ as an eigenvalue, is the $\text{rank}(A)$ always smaller than $n$?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: If a matrix is singular, then one of its eigenvalues is zero, and it is no trouble to build a singular matrix with none of its entries being zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ obtained as $uv^T$, where $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ and none of the entries of $u$ and $v$ are zero.

$\color{blue}{\text{This matrix $A = uv^T$ has no zero entries since $A(i,j) = u(i)v(j)$, where both $u(i)$ and $v(j)$ }}$ $\color{blue}{\text{are non-zero for all $i,j \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$}}$.

However, $\color{red}{\text{the matrix $A$ has $n-1$ eigenvalues as zero}}$.

One of the many equivalent definitions of rank of a matrix is the number of non-zero eigenvalues of the matrix. Hence, if $r$ eigenvalues of a matrix are non-zero, then the matrix has rank $r$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}\binom1{-1}=\;?$$

The answer to your second question, however, is *yes*, because the nullity of $A$ is positive; use the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).